# DCPSInfoRepo Killed

Tags: data-distribution-service, opendds

I am looking into OpenDDS, since I don't have the Ubuntu I am using Virtual Box and Osboxes.org VB image. When I am running the example which is provided by them, it says that the DCPSInfoRepo Is killed. Please can anyone help me? The image is attached below.[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The killing of the DCPSInfoRepo is intentional in this example, it is a service started at the start of the test and just killed at the end. It is a central repository for OpenDDS, I would recommend you to use RTPS as discovery protocol, that doesn't use a singleton service.